# why add xmlns="" in the attribute of a node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using C# and XDcoument to add nodes the root element. I use this code:

```
XElement miAnimalNuevo = new XElement("PrincipalNode",
                new XAttribute("Atribute1", "value attribute 1"),
                new XAttribute("Attribute2", "value attribute 2"),
                new XElement("subNode","0000"));
```

But I get this:

```
<PrincipalNode Atribute1="value attribute 1" Attribute2="value attribute 2" xmlns="">
    <subNode>0000</subNode>
  </PrincipalNode>
```

After the attribute 2, I see the xmlns="". Why? I only want the attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955878/xelement-is-automatically-adding-xmlns-to-itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you have an XML document that has a namespace defined somewhere up the tree.

Adding an element that is not in that namespace but in the empty namespace (i.e., *no namespace*) will add an empty `xmlns` attribute.

```
<xml xmlns="some_namespace_uri">
  <foo>The foo element inherits the 'some_namespace_uri' namespace</foo>
  <bar xmlns="">The bar element is in no namespace</bar>
</xml>
```

Related: [Is xmlns="" a valid xml namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587891/is-xmlns-is-a-valid-xml-namespace)